# Trouble iterating array to average groups of 3 numbers and compare to other groups of 3 numbers

Tags: python-3.x, iteration

I have an array of 12 numbers. I am trying to create a loop that takes the first 3 and averages them. Then it compares if this is less than the next three and the three after that and so on.

I have tried elif but the there are too many conditions to state

```
import numpy as np
import math
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
for k in range(len(array)):
    target1 = array[k]
    target2 = array [k-1]
    if k<11:
        target3 = array[k+1]
    else:
        target3 = array[0]
```

## this is how i prevent IndexError: index 12 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 12

```
    targets = [target1, target2, target3]
    target = np.mean(targets)
```

## I want to compare targets to the average of (k+2,k+3,k+4) and (k+5,k+6,k+7) and (k+8,k+9,k+10)

```
    sigma = 1
    if ((target-avg)/(math.sqrt(target))>= sigma:
        print(array[k])
```

## I cannot figure out how to get values for avg based off the sum of the other three zones of the array I am comparing to

## I was thinking of doing this

```
    if k < 8:
            range1_target1 = array[k+2]
            range1_target2 = array[k+3]
            range1_target3 = array[k+4]
```

## but there were too many options for conditions to code efficiently

Answer (score 0):

First, define the average function, a function that calculates the average of the values in an iterable object:

```
def average(iterable):
    sum = 0
    for number in iterable:
        sum += number
    return sum / len(iterable)
```

This function is pretty simple. It defines a variable called "sum" and sets its initial value to 0. It then loops through the parameter "iterable", adds each and every element's value in the iterable parameter to sum. It then divides the sum of all the values (the sum variable) by the length of iterable. It returns the result as a float.

An example: The function is called. The iterable argument is assigned to the list [25, 75, -100, 20]. The sum variable is initated to 0. Through looping on iterable, it adds 25, 75, -100, and 20 to sum. Sum ends up being 20. The length of iterable, as per Python's len() method, is 4. 20 / 4 = 5.0 (A float because one slash in Python always represents true division, and returns a floating point even if the result remains the same after being casted into an int. Use two slashes for integer division), and therefore the method returns 5.0.

Back to your program. In my opinion, you should get all the averages before comparing them. Define the averages list as follows.

```
averages = []
```

Very simple. Sets the global variable "average" to an empty list.

Because you want the averages of every three numbers, you should make the iterated range's step 3, not 1. This is done as follows.

```
for counter in range(0, len(array), 3):
```

The range constructor takes in a maximum of three parameters (start, stop, step). When it takes in three parameters, it starts counting at "start", counting by "step" and stopping at "stop." It records every number counted in an immutable iterable object. When it takes in two parameters, "step" is set to 1. When it takes in one parameter, "start" is set to 0, "stop" is set to the parameter, and "step" is set to 1.

You then want to append all the averages to the list "averages". It is done as follows.

```
    averages.append(average(array[counter: counter+3: 1]))
```

The "append" method of a list adds the parameter it takes in to the end of the list. The [counter: counter+3: 1] is a slice index. The slice constructor is similar to range except it can be done with this format: start:stop[:step] and isn't iterable, but rather takes multiple elements from an iterable object and these indexes are determined by the parameters. The average of the values are recorded in the averages array.

You have now got all the averages. No need to worry about IndexError because slices ignore any out-of-range indexes without throwing Exceptions.

Next, we want to compare the averages to each other. Here's the code:

```
for i in range(0, len(averages)):
    for j in range(0, len(averages)):
        if i == j:
            #Avoid duplicate averages.
            continue
        if averages[i] < averages[j]:
            #averages[i] < averages[j]. 
            #Do something
            continue
        elif averages[i] == averages[j]:
            #averages[i] == averages[j]. 
            #Do something
            continue
        else:
            #averages[i] > averages[j]. Only possibility left. 
            #Do something
            continue
```

That's how it's done. We iterate on the indexes on averages instead of the averages itself to test for duplicates. If the indexes equal each other, then we continue on in the loop because we don't want to deal with them. Otherwise, we compare averages[i] to averages[j] and execute python statements based on the condition. You didn't specify what you wanted to do so I just handled them like duplicates, all though you shouldn't. The rest of the code is self explanatory.

Now, for the full code. No commentary:

```
def average(iterable):
    sum = 0
    for number in iterable:
        sum += number
    return sum / len(iterable)

#Same old array that you mentioned in your question
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

averages = []

for counter in range(0, len(array), 3):
    averages.append(average(array[counter: counter+3: 1]))

for i in range(0, len(averages)):
    for j in range(0, len(averages)):
        if i == j:
            #Avoid duplicate averages.
            continue
        if averages[i] < averages[j]:
            #averages[i] < averages[j]. 
            #Do something
            continue
        elif averages[i] == averages[j]:
            #averages[i] == averages[j]. 
            #Do something
            continue
        else:
            #averages[i] > averages[j]. Only possibility left. 
            #Do something
            continue
```

I tested my code by printing the result between two different averages with this code.

```
def average(iterable):
    sum = 0
    for number in iterable:
        sum += number
    return sum / len(iterable)

#Same old array that you mentioned in your question
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

averages = []

for counter in range(0, len(array), 3):
    averages.append(average(array[counter: counter+3: 1]))

for i in range(0, len(averages)):
    for j in range(0, len(averages)):
        if i == j:
            #Avoid duplicate averages.
            continue
        if averages[i] < averages[j]:
            #averages[i] < averages[j]. 
            #Do something
            print("averages[{}] < averages[{}]".format(i, j))
        elif averages[i] == averages[j]:
            #averages[i] == averages[j]. 
            #Do something
            print("averages[{}] = averages[{}]".format(i, j))
        else:
            #averages[i] > averages[j]. Only possibility left. 
            #Do something
            print("averages[{}] > averages[{}]".format(i, j))

print("Averages: ", averages)
```

And this was the output. Run the testing code above and you'll get the same result.

```
averages[0] < averages[1]
averages[0] < averages[2]
averages[0] < averages[3]
averages[1] > averages[0]
averages[1] < averages[2]
averages[1] < averages[3]
averages[2] > averages[0]
averages[2] > averages[1]
averages[2] < averages[3]
averages[3] > averages[0]
averages[3] > averages[1]
averages[3] > averages[2]
Averages:  [2.0, 5.0, 8.0, 11.0]
```

Note: I coded this in Python 3.7

Comment: While slicing removes the out of index error, does it just take the 2 or 1 values that are valid, or does it wrap around to index[0]. I am looking for it to wrap around to index [0]. I'm also looking for the slicing to move so first its index[0,1,2] compared to the other averages and then it is [1,2,3] compared to the averages

Comment: Slicing only takes valid values and doesn't wrap around.